# looping an output with document.write in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

**Question:** How can I build the string contents of a variable with a loop in javascript?

I need to do what I've done in the following script (php), but instead of outputting it to the page, I need to insert it as a string within a javascript variable.

```
$titles[1]='fire';
$titles[2]='auto';
$titles[3]='health';
$titles[4]='loan';
$titles[5]='life';

for ($x=1; $x<=5; $x++)
    {
    echo
    '
    <div class="ball">

        <p class="ball-fraction">
            <span id="attained-' . $titles[ $x ] . '-score">0</span>/<span id="required-' . $titles[ $x ] . '-score">0</span>
        </p>
        <p class="ball-title">
            ' . $titles[ $x ] . '
        </p>
    </div>
    '
    }
```

**Purpose:** Once this is done, I can use the variable as a module within a looped set of parent element. A list output within a list, put simply. Assume that this is necessary due to the dynamic nature of the page content, and for the sake of shorter code.

**Example 1:** 
[image]

*In this example, the user's 5 stat modules can be generated with php when the page loads and the information within dynamically controlled by javascript (Node based) as time passes.*

**Example 2:**
[image]

*In this example, on the other hand, the looped stat modules need to be used within another looped output (each entry in the list).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+` for string concatenation.

```
var titles = [ "fire", "auto", "home", "health", "life" ];
var result = '';
for (var x = 0; x < titles.length; x++) {
    result += '<div class="ball"> \
                <p class="ball-fraction"> \
                    <span id="attained-' . titles[x] + '-score">0</span>/<span id="required-' + titles[x] + '-score">0</span> \
                </p> \
                <p class="ball-title">'+ titles[x] + '</p> \
            </div>';
}
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: I know that maybe this is what you want, but storing html with javascript code is not a good practice of coding.

Comment: It is better to have ready hidden block template. And when you need it get it with javascript and fill it with content.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you can still output all the content. But you can set `display:none;` with css. Then when you need to display it you can do that using javascript in any place you want.

Comment: The content is generated dynamically from the array.